# Minimize modulus of three-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers

Let

$$
\begin{array}{l}
f: [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]^3 \to {\mathbb R}^+, \\
(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3) \mapsto
|2+e^{i\theta_1}+e^{i\theta_2}+e^{i\theta_3}|
\end{array}
$$

Numerical values suggest that the minimum of $f$ is $\sqrt{13}$, and is attained at the following four points : the three permutations of $(0,\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, and $(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. But I was unable so far to show it rigorously, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3):=f^2(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$$
then
$$g(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)=|2+e^{i\theta_1}+e^{i\theta_2}+e^{i\theta_3}|^2\\=(2+\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_2+\cos\theta_3)^2+(\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2+\sin\theta_3)^2$$
$g$ is minimum whenever $f$ is minimum. Consider the following optimization problem
$$\min_{\theta} g(\theta)\hspace{0.2cm}\text{subject to}\hspace{0.2cm}\theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]^3$$
where $\theta:=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$. The Lagrangian for this problem is 
$$L(\theta,\lambda,\mu):=g(\theta)+\sum_{i=1}^3\lambda_i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta_i)-\sum_{i=1}^3\mu_i\theta_i$$
where $\lambda,\mu\geqslant 0$. First order conditions wrt to $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ are 
$$-2(2+\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_2+\cos\theta_3)\sin\theta_i+2(\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2+\sin\theta_3)\cos\theta_i-\lambda_i+\mu_i=0$$
for $i=1,2,3$. These equations can be simplified further to 
$$2\sin\theta_1-\lambda_1+\mu_1=(\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_1)+(\sin\theta_3\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_3\sin\theta_1)\\=\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)+\sin(\theta_3-\theta_1)$$
Analogue
$$2\sin\theta_2-\lambda_2+\mu_2=\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)+\sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)$$
$$2\sin\theta_3-\lambda_3+\mu_3=\sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)+\sin(\theta_2-\theta_3)$$
Adding all these three equations together and using $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$ yields
$$\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2+\sin\theta_3=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i(\lambda_i-\mu_i)$$
From slackness conditions $\lambda_i(\pi/2-\theta_i)=0, \mu_i\theta_i=0$ we observe that if the optimal $\theta$ in in the interior of $[0,\pi/2]^3$ then $\lambda_i=\mu_i=0$ for $i=1,2,3$ which would force $$\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2+\sin\theta_3=0$$
Since for $\theta\in(0,\pi/2]$ we have $\sin\theta>0$ then it must be the case that the above equation is satisfied only for $\theta_1=\theta_2=\theta_3=0$ contradicting the fact that $\theta$ was an interior point. Therefore the optimal value must lie on the boundary. One can check case by case the boundary values and compare their critical values.

Comment: We already know that $5$ is not a minimum since $\sqrt{13}$ is attained as explained in the OP. No need to look at the Hessian. So what your partial answer shows is that the minimum is attained on the boundary of the domain.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy edited my answer. indeed one need only check on the boudary of the domain. the minimum cannot be obtained in the interior.